# Django template fails to evaluate only when looking up a certain field

Tags: python, django

I am working through [Section 3 of the official Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial03/) and having trouble with template variable evaluation. After adding `app_name = polls` to my `urls.py` and updating `{% url 'detail' question.id %}` to `{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}` in my template, my template is no longer successfully evaluating one of the fields in each instance of `Question`.

With the below code, `question.question_text` in `polls/index.html` is not being evaluated. Instead, literally `{{ question.question_text }}` is being displayed for each list item. However, when I change `question.question_text` to `question.pub_date` (`pub_date` is another field on the object), it is properly evaluated and the date is displayed. Additionally, `question` is evaluated to the `question.question_text` value I am looking for because of the `Question` class' `__str__` method.

**`polls/urls.py`**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

**`polls/views.py`**

```
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

**`polls/index.html`**

```
{% if latest_question_list %}

<ul>
  {% for question in latest_question_list %}
  <li>
    <a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{
      question.question_text
    }}</a>
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
<p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: What if you write {{ question.question_text }} all in a single line, including the brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran this on my dev environment and when I put {{ question.question_text }} all on one line, it worked.

Comment: Thanks. I turned off format-on-save and this fixed it, but why?